# Custom module compilation order

Tags: java, vagrant, puppet

Im trying to install our puppet modules into my local vagrant instance. We have a module `oracle_java` that basically installs `java`.

I use the following command to to this:

```
sudo puppet apply -e 'include oracle_java' --modulepath=thirdparty/:/vagrant/puppet/modules/:/home/vagrant/.puppet/modules/ --hiera_config=/vagrant/puppet/hiera.yaml
```

This gives an error:

```
Warning: Setting templatedir is deprecated. See http://links.puppetlabs.com/env-settings-deprecations
   (at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:1139:in `issue_deprecation_warning')
WARN: 2015-08-06 17:23:09 +0000: Ignoring configured merge_behavior
WARN: 2015-08-06 17:23:09 +0000: Must have 'deep_merge' gem installed.
Error: You must include the oracle_java base class before using any oracle_java sub class at /vagrant/puppet/thirdparty/oracle_java/manifests/install.pp:8 on node puppetmaster.example.com
Error: You must include the oracle_java base class before using any oracle_java sub class at /vagrant/puppet/thirdparty/oracle_java/manifests/install.pp:8 on node puppetmaster.example.com
```

Install.pp is as follows (which raises the error):

```
class oracle_java::install {
  # The base class must be included first
  if !defined(Class['oracle_java']) {
    fail('You must include the oracle_java base class before using any oracle_java sub class')
  }

  case $oracle_java::format_real {
    'rpm'   : { contain oracle_java::install::rpm }
    default : { contain oracle_java::install::targz }
  }
}
```

init.pp is [here](http://pastie.org/10333973) (too big to post in question)